# Python unit testing on class methods with no input arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Given a class with class methods that contain only `self` input:

```
class ABC():
    def __init__(self, input_dict)
        self.variable_0 = input_dict['variable_0']
        self.variable_1 = input_dict['variable_1']
        self.variable_2 = input_dict['variable_2']
        self.variable_3 = input_dict['variable_3']

    def some_operation_0(self):
        return self.variable_0 + self.variable_1

    def some_operation_1(self):
        return self.variable_2 + self.variable_3
```

**First question**: Is this very bad practice? Should I just refactor `some_operation_0(self)` to explicitly take the necessary inputs, `some_operation_0(self, variable_0, variable_1)`? If so, the testing is very straightforward.

**Second question**: What is the correct way to setup my unit test on the method `some_operation_0(self)`? 
Should I setup a fixture in which I initialize `input_dict`, and then instantiate the class with a mock object?

```
@pytest.fixture
def generator_inputs():
    f = open('inputs.txt', 'r')
    input_dict = eval(f.read())
    f.close()
    mock_obj = ABC(input_dict)

def test_some_operation_0():
    assert mock_obj.some_operation_0() == some_value
```

(I am new to both python and general unit testing...)

Comment: off topic: your don't pass `self` in your `__init__` method

Comment: @Tino, good catch, I corrected that in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Those methods do take an argument: `self`.  There is no need to mock anything.  Instead, you can simply create an instance, and verify that the methods return the expected value when invoked.

For your example:

```
def test_abc():    
    a = ABC({'variable_0':0, 'variable_1':1, 'variable_2':2, 'variable_3':3))
    assert a.some_operation_0() == 1
    assert a.some_operation_1() == 5
```

If constructing an instance is very difficult, you might want to change your code so that the class can be instantiated from standard in-memory data structures (e.g. a dictionary).  In that case, you could create a separate function that reads/parses data from a file and uses the "data-structure-based" `__init__` method, e.g. `make_abc()` or a class method.

If this approach does not generalize to your real problem, you could imagine providing programmatic access to the *key names* or other metadata that ABC recognizes or cares about.  Then, you could programmatically construct a "defaulted" instance, e.g. an instance where every value in the input dict is a default-constructed value (such as `0` for `int`):

```
class ABC():
    PROPERTY_NAMES = ['variable_0', 'variable_1', 'variable_2', 'variable_3']

    def __init__(self, input_dict):
        # implementation omitted for brevity
        pass

    def some_operation_0(self):
        return self.variable_0 + self.variable_1

    def some_operation_1(self):
        return self.variable_2 + self.variable_3

def test_abc():
    a = ABC({name: 0 for name in ABC.PROPERTY_NAMES})
    assert a.some_operation_0() == 0
    assert a.some_operation_1() == 0
```